# macOS doesn't remember a network folder account

Tags: macos, mac

After updating my Mac Mini to **Mac OS Sonoma**, a network folder that i have been using for years (which i access via access via user-password) began to ask me for the account to access the network folder on every Mac reboot (when i open the folder).

[image]

Even if i enable the option to remember my account details, you are still asked to enter the data (once after the reboot).

Could it be caused by some particular setting? Any privacy enablements? Permissions?

Comment: These usually save to Keychain Access, so you may have an incorrect entry in there? Try and delete any entries for the server you're connecting to, then it should save new credentials correctly the next time you connect and enter them

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also forgot another important step. I had also updated the user I was connecting with. Deleted the old user and made a new user to connect to that network folder.

Comment: I proceeded to delete from the "Keychain Access" all references to the account I use to connect to that network folder (both the old and the new), but the situation does not change. Even more strangely, after the reboot, when I am asked for the account, the old username is returned to me in the field "nome" -> "name".

Comment: At this moment in "Keychain Access" I only have the new account saved.

Comment: Take a look at the properties of the link to the server - you used to be able to (maybe still can?) pass the username+pw by entering them in the URL you're connecting with, like `smb://user@server/folder`. Maybe you have it saved there?

Comment: When I changed the account I changed both the username and password. I searched the entire "Keychain Access" for the old username and there is no reference. Even within the link URLs. Very strange.

Comment: found the problem!!! It was the shortcut on the desktop that "remembered" the old username.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the properties of the shortcut to the server - you can pass the username+pw by entering them in the URL you're connecting with, like `smb://user@server/folder`. Maybe you have it saved there?